# I need to make sure to use the latest response from jquery get or post

Tags: jquery

I have a big form, where changing any value is supposed to trigger an ajax call to the server, perform some calculations and return the result. But the problem is, the users won't wait for each ajax call to finish, and after a few such calls piles-up, the result I get last may not be for the most recent call to server, because the response times for each ajax call may and will vary based on data and other factors involved. But I need to make sure that I present the user with the data that corresponds to the most recent change. So,

1) Is there a way to avoid this scenario, while using $.get() or $.post()?

2) Is there a way to use synchronous/asynchronous in the above two methods? or do I have to use $.ajax()?

EDIT:

I am using a simple ajax method

```
$("#someField").blur(function(e){

    $.get("someURL.php?v="+$(this).val(),function(d){

       $("#result").html(d);
    });

})
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a snippet of the code you have been using? Using the .get or .post callback function would enable you to call other functions upon receiving the returned result.

Comment: I modified my post, see above

Comment: I think you would need to use recursive callbacks- get it to call itself but with different parameters whenever it's completed whatever it's doing in the backend

Comment: @MattFletcher can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood- I thought you wanted to submit *all* the values but make sure they're in the correct order. I was about to do a JSfiddle that would involve a kind of timed queue system but I reckon @justin-john's answer's probably the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you calling the same request again before finishing previously called same request, then you want to abort prevoius request and proceed with new request.

```
var xhr = null;
$("#someField").blur(function(e){
    if(xhr)xhr.abort();
        xhr=$.get("someURL.php?v="+$(this).val(),function(d){
              $("#result").html(d);
            }).done(function() { xhr = null; });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

2) You can use this, to set ajax calls sync or async:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
```

After this function call, the following ajax calls ($.ajax, $.post, $.get) runs syncronous.
And i think you can use async parameter in post and get method like in ajax method. (but not sure)

But i does not recommend it. Javascript should be used as an async language.
You should rather stop previous calls. As the other commenter wrote.

Comment: Indeed no. Never ever ever ever ever use {async: false}.

Comment: @Kovge Thanks a lot for the help, but could you also explain why I shouldn't use synchronous mode? Other than the obvious usability lag, are there any other potential issues?

Comment: @aoi . If you interrested in async vs sync ajax calling, this article may be interresting for you: http://javascript.about.com/od/ajax/a/ajaxasyn.htm

Answer (score 0):

If ajax calls does not making any changes in data (just calculating and reading). That would be ok if you will abort any previous calls before calling ajax again.

Comment: how exactly do I check and abort previous unfinished requests??

Answer (score 0):

One method that the jQuery Autocomplete plugin (http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) uses is to include the query in the response to ensure that the results shown are for the correct query.

In your case, you could consider including an increasing request code with each ajax request and tracking that in jQuery. On receiving a response you could compare that with the current request code to determine if the result is for the latest query or for a previous query. While the latest response received is lower than the latest query sent, you could give a visual cue that some operations are pending, or all results are included. Of course, we'll need some additional info to ensure that this is possible in your case.

Not sure if I understand your second question - Kovge above may have answered that.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, jqXHR objects support the `abort()` method of the underlying XMLHttpRequest object, allowing unresolved/unrejected ajax requests to be aborted.

This can be done by keeping a reference to the jqXHR object returned by the previous `$.get()`.

```
var blurPromise;

$("#someField").blur(function(e) {
    if(blurPromise) blurPromise.abort();
    blurPromise = $.get("someURL.php?v="+$(this).val(), function(d) {
       $("#result").html(d);
    });
});
```

The `if(blurPromise)` test is there to handle the initial condition, when blurPromise is undefined.

There's no need ever to null out blurPromise. Calling `abort()` on a resolved jqXHR will simply be ignored.